# Object "jumps" when I press G

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make little adjustments to the position of an object. When I press <kbd>G</kbd>, the object jumps once to a position far away.... which makes it practically impossible to tweak the position slightly. See image. This happens with almost all objects in my scene.

I have the geometry set to the center of the object and the scaling is applied.

[image: object jumps wildly when pressing G]

Comment: i can just assume that you have enabled snapping: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VYdZ.png so just click it to turn it off. If this doesn't help, please provide blend file. thx

Comment: this is the answer, thank you! I had snapping on. So silly, thank you.

Comment: I am thoroughly amused that the mods HEAVILY edited my post for grammar and sentence structure.  Serious dedication here.   Surprisingly the mods even removed my "thank you" at the end of my post.  hahaha.     Fascinating!!